# How to set the height of a tableView section outside any tableView method?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView with six sections, and I need to set the height of each section separately and from outside of any tableView default method, e.g. from a button action method. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you think you need the height of the section? The table view will calculate that itself from the height of the rows in the section.

Comment: And is it not possible to have different section heights and rows scrolling if needed?

Comment: As you have been told, the height of a section is based on the height of all of the rows in the section. So of course each section can have different heights. Simply use any combination of row count and row height. You still haven't explained what you are trying to do and why you think you need to know the section height.

Comment: I thought I could set a fixed section height, so the sections could all be shown on a single view, then if needed, the user could scroll over the rows, inside the frame of the section height, without interfering the rest of the sections. Do you understand me now?

Comment: Your are talking about a `UITableView`, right? If so, what you describe makes no sense. What single view do you mean?

Comment: As example, imagine you have three sections. First section has 50 rows, second section has two rows and third section has five rows. If it is not possible to set the section height, the user will only see part of the rows from the first section. If I could set the section height, I would be able to show the three sections on a single device screen, and the user could navigate scrolling the rows to see the 50 rows from the first section, but having in view all sections.

Comment: That's not how a table view works. There is no such concept as a section height. What you describe is not a feature built into `UITableView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the height of each row, because the height of the section would be determined by the number of rows and the height of each row.

Ultimately, the tableView rowHeight method needs to be used. You can use flags within your class to keep track of certain conditions and change those flags at the tap of a button and reload your table's data.

Comment: Thank you, as i explain in the answer, my tableView has 6 fixed sections. What I want is to determine the height of each section and no taking into account the number of rows or the height of the rows. I guess that setting the height of the sections, the rows will be included in a scrollView automatically.